# Socket writing problem with TCP/IP

Tags: c++, networking, symbian

I am using TCP/IP socket example i.e. "echoclient", and I am facing problems with writing and reading.

I am connecting to server socket but it shows null data. I don't know whether it is data conversion problem or any other issue.

Comment: Could you post some code, perhaps we can see where you went wrong.

Comment: Are you saying the attempt to connect fails? ..or that the data you send doesn't arrive?

Comment: jon is right, your server might not be sending anything.  what level of sockets are you writing? Socket, AsyncSocket?

Answer (score 1):

Download [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and see if it helps debug.  It can peek all network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are connecting via mobile, check with your GPRS/EDGE/3G service provider if they are not restricting arbitrary IPs ?

Also in case if you're connecting from Simulator on PC, check if you have Proxies over your network before internet ?

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to use well tested libraries and implementation. Socket programming is c++ requires good understanding of OS if you want to write potable code. 
Try Ace Wrappers - http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html It provide well tested pattern based C++ implementation for distributed network programming.